# Using pictures in the project

Tags: java, android, image, performance, memory

I have a question. The project on the main screen I use 7 images in .png format size for 50 - 60 kb. At the same time when the application runs on the phone Monitor shows that the device uses 20 mb memory. How to upload pictures to use as little memory? Thanks for the answer.

I used the standard installation in the layout, the installation program

```
  main_image.setImageDrawable(getResources(getDrawable(R.drawable.main).);
```

and glide

```
  library(Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(R.drawable.main).placeholder(R.color.white).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.NONE).skipMemoryCache(true).into(main_image);),
```

it is not bad but quite long loads images.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html

Comment: Or you could use Volley image loader, or Picasso or Glide, etc. Many image libraries to choose from

Comment: Please provide relevant portions of your code, especially how you load and handle the images. You can add the information by editing your initial post.

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to the post [Images taking too much memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42176323/7550472). The reason why for a small sized image you are getting large memory consumption is most likely due to usage of high pixelled images that use up more of your space when stored in Bitmaps. Infact I realised the **answer for the high memory usage for small images** just today when **Dimezis** pointed out my folly in just considering size and not looking into **resolution** of the image ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42294889/7550472)).

Now for the solution, I would recommend using [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), a image loading library that is pretty widely used. In it, there is an option to load the images in **RGB_565** which can **decrease your memory consumption by about half** (have *seen the results practically*) and many more. [Link to a more detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42296542/7550472).

And ofcourse I recommend you too to look into the