# Images taking too much memory

Tags: android, image, memory

Hi I have pretty simply code my images are all compressed so no one has more than 50kb. When I start my app 1 image is loaded and memory usage is around 42mb but when I scroll down to another images every other image cause memory usage to increase up to 250mb. How to fix it? Here is my code and please I am beginner so try to explain it simple.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class CustomSwip extends PagerAdapter {
private int[] imageResources = {R.drawable.j1, R.drawable.jg2,R.drawable.jg3, R.drawable.jg4, R.drawable.jg5, R.drawable.jg6, R.drawable.jg7, R.drawable.jg8, R.drawable.jg9, R.drawable.jg10, R.drawable.jg11, R.drawable.jg12, R.drawable.jg13, R.drawable.jg14, R.drawable.jg15, R.drawable.jg16};
private Context ctx;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public CustomSwip(Context c) {
    ctx = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {

    return imageResources.length;
}


@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_custom_swip, container, false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.swip_image_view);
    imageView.setImageResource(imageResources[position]);
    container.addView(itemView);
    return itemView;
}


@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

}


@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {

    return (view == object);
}

}
```

Comment: Use `Glide` or `Picasso` library for image downloading/caching.

Comment: what do you mean by memory usage? is it the storage memory used for your app in your device memory?

Comment: Android Monitor has a main window that contains the logcat, Memory, CPU, GPU, and Network Monitors. From this window, you can select a device and app process to work with, terminate an app, collect dumpsys system information, and create screenshots and videos of the running app.Its this memory from android monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) is a library by [nostra13](https://github.com/nostra13) which is pretty *well documented* and *widely used* and is known for the **configuration setting** it provides for loading of images. In it, there is an option to load the  images in **RGB_565** which can decrease your memory consumption by about half (have seen the results practically) and many more.

> Use .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) in display options. Bitmaps in RGB_565 consume 2 times less memory than in ARGB_8888.

And do look into [WeakReferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html) once. It could help in calling of Garbage Collector for memory-intensive images.

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs for setImageResource,

> This does Bitmap reading and decoding on the UI thread, which can cause a latency hiccup. If that's a concern, consider using setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable) or setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap) and BitmapFactory instead.

Or simply use an image loading library to lazy load images