# Lottie animation slow android

Tags: android, animation

I'm using Airbnb's new library, [Lottie](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) to make an animation in my app.

The animation consists of a 70 kb JSON file and a 328 kb images folder. There's 13 small pngs in this folder.

Following the GitHub repo's indications, I declare my view like this

```
    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
    android:id="@+id/lottie_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:lottie_fileName="animation.json"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:lottie_loop="false"
    app:lottie_autoPlay="true"/>
```

and then, on the pertinent java class I call:

```
        mLottieView.setImageAssetsFolder("images");
```

However, I have a problem. The animation is clunky and slow and my memory usage jumps through the roof. It goes from 13 MB to 89, all of this happening on the main thread.

Could you tell me if there is a way to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: I'm in the same shoes. Will check back for answer.

Comment: can you share the thing and also the dimensions for the container? also what do you mean by 'all of this happening on the main thread'?

Comment: I mean that the animations themselves and the and the bitmap transformations happen on the main thread, thus making the app clunky. The container width is set to match_parent and the height is wrap_content. In dps it's about 500 x 500

Comment: Lottie author here: can you post an issue on the github issue and attach your animation? I'll take a look!

Comment: mLottieView.useHardwareAcceleration(); use this.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [documentation](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android) mentions a few items which affect performance

> - If the composition has no masks or mattes then the performance and memory overhead should be quite good
> - Png sequences are even worse than gifs (due to file sizes)

There are also some generic Android/mobile concerns to consider:

- With the `width="match_parent", height="wrap_content"` combination, the images will be scaled up. Use wrap, wrap or a fixed size.
- Alpha on PNGs adds additional overhead to processing

If your UI thread is doing too much work as you suggest, can you hold off on starting your animation? If that's an option then [LottieComposition](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/LottieComposition.java) has static methods such as `LottieComposition.fromJson()`.

You could manually set up your compositions on a background thread (and then optionally create a `LottieDrawable` and set the composition). Once that's finished you can switch to the UI thread and setComposition (or setImageDrawable) on the `LottieAnimationView`

Comment: Let me try this.

Answer (score 13):

I have solved this issue by using these two lines of codes

```
  final LottieAnimationView animationView = (LottieAnimationView) findViewById(R.id.animation_view);
  animationView.useExperimentalHardwareAcceleration(true);
  animationView.enableMergePathsForKitKatAndAbove(true);
```

**Update 03-2021** (to save you having to dig in the comments)

```
// deprecated
animationView.useExperimentalHardwareAcceleration(true)

// it was this for a bit, but now this is removed too
animationView.useHardwareAcceleration(true)

// confirmed this works on Lottie 3.2.0
animationView.setRenderMode(RenderMode.HARDWARE)
```

Comment: are those features still experimental?

Comment: You can use `animationView.useHardwareAcceleration(true);` instead. The experimental method is currently marked as `deprecated`.
Using version **2.2.3**

Comment: PS: for me, it messes up the animation.

Comment: I'm afraid `animationView.useHardwareAcceleration(true)` doesn't do it for me either.

Comment: Does this not exist anymore? neither `useExperimentalHardwareAcceleration` nor `useHardwareAcceleration` are available in `3.2.2`

Comment: I don't know @behelit I have left using android studio now.

Comment: @behelit : it's been replaced with .. Replaced enableHardwareAcceleration with a new setRenderMode API because it has a third (Automatic) option. Refer to the docs for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your "small images" and memory consumption problem, I was already answering a quite similar question:

[Huge spike in memory consumption when using png with lot of transparent area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293642/huge-spike-in-memory-consumption-when-using-png-with-lot-of-transparent-area/42294889#42294889)

Don't be confused by 328kb images folder. In memory those images will take much-much more space. And this is the reason you have memory consumption jump.

Allocating and garbage collecting this amount of Bitmaps during animation will always be accompanied by lags.

Answer (score 0):

A little strange is testing using below a drawerlayout and inside a toolbar was horrible but this worked for me.

I have not tried it yet using other devices but on a physical android 12 it works great for me.

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                app:lottie_renderMode="software"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the ones coming for Lottie React Native, you can pass these two props to use hardware acceleration. This solved the performance issues for me in Android.

```
<Lottie
  {...otherProps}
  renderMode="HARDWARE"
  hardwareAccelerationAndroid={true}
/>
```